# UPDATE SET em um registro

Tags: php, html, mysql

Galera eu tenho uma tabela que lista registros no banco de dados e na frente de cada registro tem um botão dessa forma

```
<a href="index.php?mod=pedidos&funcao=editar&id=<?=$lnped['protocolo']?>" class="ls-btn-primary ls-ico-user"></a>
```

`$lnped['protocolo']` vem do banco de dados é o numero do registro

e eu preciso que ao clicar nesse botão ele altere o campo "PRODUZIDO" do registro selecionado para '1' só que quando eu clico ele altera todos os que estão na tabela e não só o que eu cliquei

aqui está meu codigo

```
<?php
    $idget = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    $produzir = isset($_GET['funcao']) ? $_GET['funcao'] : '';
    $consultapedidos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE protocolo = '".$idget."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($consultapedidos)==true){
    if($produzir == "editar"){

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE pedidos SET produzido = '1'") ;  

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;' URL= index.php?mod=pedidos>";
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use o stacksnippets apenas pra códigos que podem ser reproduzidos, se não sabe formatar a questão, clique no botão com sinal de interrogação que aparece quando esta editando ou escrevendo uma pergunta e verá as dicas, tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Tá em PHP, se eu colocar snippets n vai mostrar o codigo certo.

Comment: Não é só esta a questão de mostrar algo, é a questão de se algo executa ou não, recomendo que leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/js-css-e-html-executáveis-no-corpo-da-pergunta-ou-resposta e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2363/como-tornar-o-uso-do-snippet-mais-intuitivo . Tenho certeza que você irá levar minhas dicas como construtivas e entender que estou apenas lhe orientando :)

Comment: Na tabela _pedidos_ existe também o campo _protocolo_ ?

Comment: Mas o campo protocolo só existe na tabela pedidos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que seu `UPDATE` não tem uma cláusula `WHERE`, ou seja, vai atualizar todos os registros no banco.

Para que isso funcione altere seu `UPDATE` para:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pedidos SET produzido = '1' WHERE protocolo = '".$idget."'");
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Diego! Dê uma olhada nas opções de formatação para os seus posts [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - e veja umas dicas de como responder perguntas [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). :)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE pedidos SET produzido = '1' WHERE protocolo = '".$idget."'"
```

Comment: Seria útil se acrescentasse uma explicação em como esse Update é uma resposta válida para a pergunta.

Comment: Não tive capacidade para tanto, se você fizer a gentileza fico agradecido.

Comment: Ele não deu explicação nem nada mas deu pra entender, então de qualquer forma obrigado, funcionou corretamente..